# Android: Translating a menu from bottom

Tags: android, menu, translate

I tried a lot to translate my menu from bottom and couldn't able to solve. I have a frame animation for 30 seconds on completing this animation I want to show my menu with translate animation from bottom.   any Idea?

In the run method of the code I want to add the translation. Is it possible to do so?

here is the code

Help is always appreciated.....! Thanks

```
if (ekgframeAnimation4.isRunning()) {
                        // ekgimgview4.postDelayed(ekgframeAnimation4, 30000);
                          findViewById(R.id.ekgimgview4).postDelayed(new Runnable()
                           { 
                                 public void run()
                                 { 
                                // I want to show my own popup menu here


                                 }
                             }, 30000);

                        ekgframeAnimation4.stop();

                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check this post, it may be helpful to you.
[View Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)